# find and replace in JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, text-editor

I am creating an editor in java using JEditorPane. I have managed to create functionality for find function using Highlighters. I want to add replace functionality to it.. thnx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should go by

```
Document doc = editorPane.getDocument();

// remove the text you want to replace
doc.remove(startingOffset, length);

// add replacement
doc.insertString(startingOffset, newText, attributes);
```

Of course you need to know where the text you want to replace starts and how long it is..

Comment: what to pass in attributes argument

Comment: they are the attributes of the text (color, style and so on..), not related to your question anyway http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/AttributeSet.html